# How to control X11 viewport from an application

Tags: x11, xrandr

Suppose we have an X11 display configured in panning mode. E.g.

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1920x1080 --panning 4096x4096
```

Is there a way to move the visible viewport from a user application (ideally in a way that would handle several viewport updates per second).

Comment: Can you do it with `xrandr` ?

Comment: If it's possible, I haven't found it there. I want to use accelerometer data to pan the viewport according to the head angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man xdotool says it can get/set the viewport:

```
   get_desktop_viewport [--shell]
       Report the current viewport's position. If --shell is given, the
       output is friendly to shell eval.

   set_desktop_viewport x y
       some windowmangers only obey requests that align to workspace boundaries
```

Comment: Looks like that's exactly what I need! Thanks a ton!